# can not search a user name in repositories those I have starred

Tags: github, github-api

Is there any way to find a user in my starred repo list?

For e.g. I have starred 3 or 4 repos from the user:

https://github.com/pemistahl

But there seems to be no way to get that list.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to work if you search for `user:pemistahl`  A little like searching for an author in issues `is:issue is:open author:@me`

[image]